# non-working transition for mobile navigation in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, css-transitions

I gave transition to the navigation that appears when the state menu is set to true but the transition doesn't work

```
{ menu && <div className={`fixed transition-all duration-300 ${menu ? 'top-0' : 'top-[100%]'} inset-0 bg-white flex justify-center items-center`}>
        <ul className="flex flex-col gap-9 text-xl items-center font-medium cursor-pointer">
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Home</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>O nas</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Oferta</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Galeria</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Kariera</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Kontakt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>}
```

I hope you can help me find the problem!
I am attaching the entire code below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "../images/logo.PNG";
import { GiHamburgerMenu } from "react-icons/gi";
import { ImCross } from "react-icons/im";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);

  return (
    <header className="mx-auto container py-4 px-4 xl:px-8 border">
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center w-full">
        <img
          className="mx-auto md:mx-0 h-[70px] w-[220px] xl:h-[100px] xl:w-[300px] object-cover"
          src={logo}
          alt="logo"
        />

        <ul className="hidden md:flex gap-4 xl:gap-8 text-base xl:text-xl font-medium cursor-pointer">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>O nas</li>
          <li>Oferta</li>
          <li>Galeria</li>
          <li>Kariera</li>
          <li>Kontakt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      {menu ? (
            <ImCross onClick={()=>setMenu(false)} className="flex md:hidden fixed bottom-8 right-8 z-10 text-white bg-black w-16 h-16 p-4 rounded-full cursor-pointer" />
      ) : (
        <GiHamburgerMenu onClick={()=>setMenu(true)} className="flex md:hidden fixed bottom-8 right-8 z-10 text-white bg-black w-16 h-16 p-4 rounded-full cursor-pointer" />
      )}
{ menu && <div className={`fixed transition-all duration-300 ${menu ? 'top-0' : 'top-[100%]'} inset-0 bg-white flex justify-center items-center`}>
        <ul className="flex flex-col gap-9 text-xl items-center font-medium cursor-pointer">
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Home</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>O nas</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Oferta</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Galeria</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Kariera</li>
          <li onClick={()=> setMenu(false)}>Kontakt</li>
        </ul>
      </div>}
    </header>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.